# Increase tex font size throughout the application WSS SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to provide an option to have a text font size let say 16px throught the web site while creating ite.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply / specify an alternate Css file through the site settings -> Master page

Answer (score 0):

You need to attack with a CSS Class. Override the Font Size for the CSS that you want to change refer to [this](http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm) link for list of CSS class Used in WSS